# Cases for Fermat like equations $a_1^{n_1}+a_2^{n_2}+\cdots+a_m^{n_m}=z^c$

Tags: number-theory

What are possible cases of solutions for 
$a_1^{n_1}+a_2^{n_2}+\cdots+a_m^{n_m}=z^c$ like integer equations?

For example the case $m=2$ and $n_1=n_2=c=2$ is Pythagorean triplets having infinite many solutions.

The case $m=2$ and $n_1=n_2=c>2$ is the Fermat's theorem and there are no solutions.

What about the case $m>2$ and $n_k=c>2$ (i.e. Fermat's theorem with more than 2 integers )or

case $m=2$ and $n_1 (= \vee \neq) n_2 (= \vee \neq) c$ (i.e. Fermat's theorem with powers that can vary).

Is there any classification of these types of equations having fintely or infinitely many solutions depending on number of variables and differing values of powers.

Comment: These links: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation3rdPowers.html, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiophantineEquation4thPowers.html, ... are about $n_1=n_2=...=n_m=c$. And Tito Piezas III's collection: https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/Home.

Comment: About $m=2$: famous $10$ solutions of Fermat$-$Catalan conjecture: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%E2%80%93Catalan_conjecture.